# How to upgrade NodeJS on openshift 3 (nextgen)?

Tags: node.js, openshift, openshift-origin

Openshift 3 have nodejs v5 , but my app need nodejs v6 .
How to upgrade NodeJS on openshift 3 (nextgen) ?
i cant find any tutorial or document about this work for new version of openshift .

Comment: Consider looking at this builder image. https://github.com/ryanj/origin-s2i-nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just noticed that in the redhat registry there is now a v6 if your strictly rhel.

https://access.redhat.com/containers/#/registry.access.redhat.com/rhscl-beta/nodejs-6-rhel7